# How to cast from string to int

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the string from " src".."data-lazy-" in variable **str**, and it's work when i hard code it...

```
var str = "<h1 style=\"font-family: Helvetica\">Hello Pizza</h1><p>Tap the buttons above to see <strong>some cool stuff</strong> with <code>UIWebView</code><p><img src=\"https://apppie.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/photo-sep-14-7-40-59-pm_small1.jpg\" data-lazy-src=\"xxxxxxx\">"

str.rangeOfString(" src")?.startIndex
str.rangeOfString("data-lazy-")?.endIndex

let myNSString = str as NSString

myNSString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 150, length: 245-150))
```

Result:  `src=\"https://apppie.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/photo-sep-14-7-40-59-pm_small1.jpg\" data-lazy-`

---

Here, i'm trying not to hard code it...

```
var str = "<h1 style=\"font-family: Helvetica\">Hello Pizza</h1><p>Tap the buttons above to see <strong>some cool stuff</strong> with <code>UIWebView</code><p><img src=\"https://apppie.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/photo-sep-14-7-40-59-pm_small1.jpg\" data-lazy-src=\"xxxxxxx\">"

str.rangeOfString(" src")?.startIndex
str.rangeOfString("data-lazy-")?.endIndex

let myNSString = str as NSString

let start = str.startIndex.toInt()
let end   = str.endIndex.toInt()

myNSString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: start, length: end - start))
```

The code above show error message ***'String.index' does not have a member named 'toInt'***
 My question is how could i solve this problem? 
Sorry, i am a fairly new to swift programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting is not the problem.

The method `substringWithRange()` accepts an argument of `Range` - a Swift range - and a `Range` can be created with arguments of type `String.Index`.  Thus use:

```
// I'm ignoring optionals; this code is unsafe and thus only an example
let beg = str.rangeOfString(" src")!
let end = str.rangeOfString("data-lazy-")!

str.substringWithRange(Range(start: beg.endIndex, end: end.startIndex))
```

Specifically:

```
 15> var str = "abc src=def xyz" 
str: String = "abc src=def xyz"
 16> var si = str.rangeOfString("src=")!
si: Range<String.Index> = { ... }
 17> var ei = str.rangeOfString(" xyz")!
ei: Range<String.Index> = { ... }
 18> str.substringWithRange(Range (start: si.endIndex, end: ei.startIndex))
$R3: String = "def"
```

Don't be confused by the word 'Index' in 'String.Index' - this is not like 'i' in `s[i]`.  A `String.Index` is an opaque data type; it behaves more like a pointer (in a C-like language).  A `String.Index` has lots to account for in the Unicode world of Swift strings.